# What is the difference between using os.system and the subprocess module, generally, and as it pertains to clearing the console?

Tags: python, console, operating-system, subprocess

If I have a function that I use in my program to clear the console:

```
import os  

def clear():  
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
```

calling `clear()` would clear the user's console and be a cross-platform way of doing so

With the subprocess module, I can do the following for windows, but how could I make it work crossplatform like the original function above:

```
import subprocess as sp

def clear():
    sp.call('cls', shell=True)
```

I have also seen the following, but am struggling to understand the difference:

```
import subprocess as sp  

def clear():  
    _ = sp.call('cls', shell=True)
```

What exactly is the purpose of the variable assignment?

would `subprocess.run()` have any relevance or is the `subprocess.call()` method the one to use?

and more generally, is their an advantage to using the subprocess module?

Comment: "What exactly is the purpose of the variable assignment?" there is none.

Answer (score 1):

Do it the same way:

```
sp.call(('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear'), shell=True)
```

One advantage of using `subprocess` is that you can execute the program directly, without using the shell:

```
sp.call(['cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear'])
```

Comment: thankyou. But Im curious, is their any advantage to doing it this way, compared to  using os.system()

Comment: I've updated the answer to show what you can do with `subprocess`.